# Angularjs input text value from json

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to load json data on the form which has two text fields. TextFields display correct price and qty from json. But, the problem is when user updates the price and qty, updated price and qty are not reflecting in controller method - $scope.total(). Here is my code

**HTML file**

```
<div ng-repeat="row in myData">
<input type="text" ng-model="row.price"> 
<input type="text" ng-model="row.qty"> 
</div>
```

**JS file**

```
$http.get('http call’).success(function(data){
          $scope. myData = data
        })

$scope.row = {
            price :  10.0,
            qty : 2;
        };

$scope.total = function() {
      console.log($scope.row.price);
      console.log($scope.row.qty);
}
```

**JSON** - [{"price":10.50,"qty":3}]

Not sure what I am missing here? why updated values are not reflecting in controller?

Comment: row keyword inside ng-repeat is totally different that $scope.row

Comment: What would be the correct way to populate and bind with model. appreciate your time. Thanks

Comment: does that myData will contain only one element?

Comment: Let me correct - myData will have only one element.

Comment: Answer added, i believe myData should be an json without array if it doesn't include more than one value.

Comment: No luck, is there a way to display json data in text using ng-value, value etc and not by using ng-model (i will leave ng-model for binding).

Answer (score 0):

Your `$scope.total` function needs to be called somewhere, and as mentioned by @pankajparkar, `$scope.row` is different than the `row` in your directive (which belongs to the ng-repeat's scope only).

Do this:

```
<div ng-repeat="row in myData">
<input type="text" ng-model="row.price" ng-change="total()"> 
<input type="text" ng-model="row.qty" ng-change="total()">
</div>
```

JS:

```
$http.get('http call').success(function(data){
    $scope.myData = data;
});

$scope.total = function() {
    console.log($scope.myData[0].price * $scope.myData[0].qty);
};
```

Comment: myData.price? are you crazy?

Comment: myData = [{"price":10.50,"qty":3}] as mentioned by @Xavier G

Comment: I called total() on ng-change. But, still updated values from text fields are not passed to controller total method

Comment: Sorry, about that, since myData is an array you need to specify the index in your function, `$scope.myData[0].price`. I updated my answer, it works now, I just tested it.

Answer (score 0):

As your data is an array you loop througt is to get the total of all your objects:

```
$scope.total = function() {
    var sum = 0;
    myData.forEach(function(obj){
        sum += obj.qty * obj.price
    });

    return sum;
}
```

and you need to call this function when values change.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/11670/)

---

With only one element in your array, your function `total` should be like @Joao answer:

```
$scope.total = function() {
    return $scope.myData[0].price * $scope.myData[0].qty;
};
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/11671/)

Comment: Or you could use angular.forEach instead of jQuery: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach

Comment: it's only javacript not jQuery: [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/forEach)

Comment: Oh your right! I learn something every day! I always thought it was jQuery.

Comment: My issue is - when user updates price in text field, updated price is not getting reflected in total(). And, I am calling total().

Comment: and i have only one data element. so i dont have to loop

Answer (score 0):

First thing if response is only one item then it should not be an array

It should be Single JSON such as `{"price":10.50,"qty":3}`

**HTML Code**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myData.price"> 
<input type="text" ng-model="myData.qty"> 
<button type="button" ng-click="updateTotal()">
```

**JS CODE**

```
$http.get('http call').success(function(data){
    $scope.myData = data;
});

$scope.total = function(){
  //now here you will get updated scope values
  console.log($scope.myData.price * $scope.myData.qty);
}
```

Hope this will be help full to you.

Comment: @Xavier G does my answer helped you?

Answer (score -1):

$scope.total is a function, but it is not returning anything.

instead of:

```
var total = $scope.row.price * $scope.row.qty
```

try:

```
return $scope.row.price * $scope.row.qty
```

Comment: In the function, i am not getting updated value printed on console.